# How can I make only a part of the window transparent? (WIN32)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How can I make for example only a rectangle inside the window have opacity like 50% or something like that and for that part to have the effect of WS_EX_TRANSPARENT so that mouse clicks will go through it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think it is possible simply by setting WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, but it can be accomplished using two windows, create a window with a hole, using [SetWindowRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930600.aspx), and inside that hole put another transparent window using WS_EX_LAYERED and WS_EX_TRANSPARENT styles.

Comment: Can just the reduced opacity part be done somehow else or would you do it in the same way just for that too?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the **SetLayeredWindowAttributes** Win32 function.

It can be used to set the *opacity* and *transparency* of a window.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this CodeProject article: [Cool, Semi-transparent and Shaped Dialogs with Standard Controls for Windows 2000 and Above](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/SemiTranDlgWithCtrls.aspx).